# Nature of the Preliminary Articles of Peace of 1782

Tags: treaty

http://avalon.law.yale.edu/18th_century/prel1782.asp

The Preliminary Articles of Peace at the URL above appear to be identical to the peace treaty usually said to be dated 1783 and ratified in 1784.

Since they are verbatim the same, what is the difference between the "Prelimary Articles" and the "Treaty"?  Why is one document considered merely preliminary rather being called a proposed treaty to be submitted for ratification by both countries?

Comment: I'd be curious to hear your definition of "preliminary."

Comment: I would be very much surprised if the preliminary articles drafted in 1782 were drafted on Yale's web site. I don't think you can say they are the same as the final treaty when you *haven't seen the actual documents*

Comment: @cpast : Is that addressed to me?  You want _my_ definition of "preliminary", as if I were the one who used that word, when a sustantial part of my posted question is why others used it?

Comment: @DaleM : I have seen photographic copies of the hand-written documents and typeset versions elsewhere, but it's been a while.